# How to calculate overlapped areas for each polygon within the same shapefile layer?

Tags: arcmap

I have a vector layer containing thoudsands of polygons. Some of these polygons are (highly) overlapped with one another.

I have two purposes:

1. identify polygons that are highly overlapped (spatially overlapped and areas are quite similar/ the same) ;
2. group these highly overlapped polygons (assign each group a common value in a column to indicate such group relationship.

   How may I implement these in ArcMap? Any hints are welcome!

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as a duplicate of your original post. Fix your original question and get that reopened. It is closed because you have both ArcMap and geopanda tags. Pick either one